# How to retrieve only rows with IDs that appear between 5 and 15 times in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this so far:

```
counts = df['ID'].value_counts()
df = df[df['ID'].isin(counts.index[counts > 5])]
counts = df['ID'].value_counts()
df = df[df['ID'].isin(counts.index[counts < 15])]
```

But this seems redundant, is there an approach to do it all within the first 2 lines?  If I put (counts > 5 and counts < 15) I get an error:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: Also, there is no need for the second: `counts = df['ID'].value_counts()`. You slice it in the `.isin` call, but because that slice is never assigned back so the changes don't stick so `counts` is unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe `groupby` + `transform` to broadcast the 'ID' size to every row of that ID, then you can create a Boolean mask to slice with using `between`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A']*6 +['B']*15 +['C']*5})

df[df.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform('size').between(5, 15, inclusive=False)]

  ID
0  A
1  A
2  A
3  A
4  A
5  A
```

---

In terms of performance between using `groupby` + `transform` or slicing the index using `value_counts` there doesn't really seem to be much of a difference. (Actually the value_counts methods seems to be slightly faster if you think you plan to filter most groups (say most have a size of 1-2) or if you plan to keep most groups (most have a size >> 15))

```
import perfplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def transform(df):
    return df[df.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform('size').between(5, 15, inclusive=False)]
    
    
def value_counts_slice(df):
    counts = df['ID'].value_counts()
    return df[df['ID'].isin(counts.index[(counts > 5) & (counts < 15)])]
            
            
perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.DataFrame({'ID': np.random.randint(0, n, 15*n)}),
    kernels=[
        lambda df: transform(df),
        lambda df: value_counts_slice(df),
    ],
    labels=["Transform", "Value Counts"],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(2,21)],
    equality_check=np.allclose,
    xlabel="Number of ID Groups"
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Any difference between this one and the other (which you also contributed to) in terms of performance? Or is the choice arbitrary?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
counts = df['ID'].value_counts()
df = df[df['ID'].isin(counts.index[(counts > 5) & (counts < 15)])]
```

Cheers!

Edited to include [ALollz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4333359/alollz)'s suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You can compare multiple conditions in the same operation.

```
counts = df['ID'].value_counts()
greater_5 = counts.index[counts > 5]
lower_15 = counts.index[counts < 15]
df_filtered = (df[
                 (df['ID'].isin(greater_5)) &
                 (df['ID'].isin(lower_15))
                ]
              )
```

You don't need to create mask variables, but is a good approach to keep code readability